# Confusing argument count error using clojures recur

Tags: clojure

I want a function that takes collections and returns the elements in a round-robin fashion.  i.e.:

```
 (round-robin [[:a1 :a2 :a3] [:b1] [:c1 :c2][)
 ;; => (:a1 :b1 :c1 :a2 :c2 :a3)
```

Something that works:

```
(defn round-robin [all-colls]
    (let [colls (filter seq all-colls)]
         (if (seq colls)
             (lazy-cat
                (map first colls)
                (round-robin (map next colls))))))  ;; recursive call
```

I'd be interested in a better idiom but this took me a while to come up with as I could not understand why this would not work with recur. e.g.

```
 (defn round-robin [all-colls]
    (let [colls (filter seq all-colls)]
         (if (seq colls)
             (lazy-cat
                (map first colls)
                (recur (map next colls))))))  ;; same with recur
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 0 args, got: 1
```

**Why does it say expected args is 0?**

Note that I get the same error if I try with `loop ... recur`.  Perhaps related to the recur with variadic [discusssed in clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur#example-55ff3cd4e4b08e404b6c1c7f) (which I don't quite grok) or lazy-cat being a recur target?

just don't understand why no version of this works with recur.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, which was already given, but rather a comment: if you need this in a multi-threaded fashion you might take a look at [https://github.com/acrolinx/clj-queue-by]/clj-queue-by). (be aware that this is a self-ad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because calls to `lazy-seq` expand to a [0-arity function.](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L682) You aren't `recur`sing into `round-robin`, you're recursing into the function that `lazy-seq` (which `lazy-cat` uses) expands into. The use of macros here is complicating things.

If you write:

```
(lazy-seq (recur))
```

This (roughly) gets turned into:

```
(LazySeq. (fn [] (recur)))
```

Note what function `recur` is actually occurring in now.

Also, as @leetwinski points out, `recur` isn't in the tail position, so this recursion couldn't be optimized anyway. If you look at the docs for `lazy-cat`, you'll see the following equality describing how the macro expands:

```
(lazy-cat xs ys zs) === (concat (lazy-seq xs) (lazy-seq ys) (lazy-seq zs))
```

In your case, `recur` is basically `zs`. It's inside the form that's in the tail position, but isn't in the position itself.

Just call the function directly instead of using `recur`. Because of how `lazy-seq` works, this won't lead to a Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would add, that even if there were no tricky macro problem here, the usage of `recur` is wrong in that example, because it is not a tail recursion, which compiler would notice.

Comment: @leetwinski Thanks. I added a blurb. I'd still argue though that this is a "macro muddying the waters" problem. If `lazy-cat` was a plain function, `recur` would, as far as I can see, be in the tail position.

Comment: yes my first comment is partly wrong. Recur is in the tail position, but that's that's the matter of the `loop/recur` design in clojure: `(loop [x 1]
         (if (>= x 10)
           []
           (cons x (recur (inc x)))))` => "CompilerException java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can only recur from tail position"

Answer (score 3):

in addition: you can make the round-robin lazy just manipulating collections in a functional way:

```
(defn round-robin [data]
  (->> data
       (filter seq)
       (iterate (partial keep next))
       (take-while seq)
       (mapcat (partial map first))))
#'user/round-robin

user> (round-robin [[:a1 :a2 :a3] [:b1] [:c1 :c2]])
;;=> (:a1 :b1 :c1 :a2 :c2 :a3)

user> (round-robin [[] []])
;;=> ()

user> (round-robin [])
;;=> ()
```

Comment: There's often no need to use low level lazy primitives. So many library functions, like what you show here, already use `lazy-seq`, it's easy to just accidentally end up with lazy code. Always check to make sure you aren't making your life difficult by trying to reinvent the wheel before you dig down and get your hands dirty with `lazy-seq`.

Comment: Although not really shorter than my solution, +1 for a very cool solution I wish I had thought of. accepted ans goes to @Carcigenicate as that answers my direct question on why I was getting the error that frustrated me for so long.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious, but this is the answer:

```
(def data [[:a1 :a2 :a3] [:b1] [:c1 :c2]])
(defn round-robin [data-seqs]
  (let
    [lengths   (for [s data-seqs] (count s))
     limit     (apply max lengths)
     coll-seqs (for [s data-seqs]
                 (take limit (concat s (repeat nil))))
     matrix    (apply map vector coll-seqs)
     keepers   (filter not-nil? (flatten matrix))
     ]
    (vec keepers)))
```

with results:

```
lengths => (3 1 2)
limit => 3
coll-seqs => ((:a1 :a2 :a3) (:b1 nil nil) (:c1 :c2 nil))
matrix => ([:a1 :b1 :c1] [:a2 nil :c2] [:a3 nil nil])
keepers => (:a1 :b1 :c1 :a2 :c2 :a3)
(round-robin data) => [:a1 :b1 :c1 :a2 :c2 :a3]
```